# Named route with dynamic parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im trying to figure out a most basic feature, to create a named route that I can include in my views and code but am unable to get it to work

```
  match '/user/:username' => "profiles#show", :as => show_profile
```

How would I be able to include in my views below code:

```
show_profile_path
```

and have it linked to /user/username ( of the user logged in )
Im using devise and rails 3.2 and searched upfront for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
link_to "cool profile", show_profile_path(username: @user.username)
```

be sure that you have right search method in Profiles_controller#show

```
@user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first
```

Comment: Havent tried this , try today, after looking op the routing docs of rails this should probably work so as I flag it corect answer